# Enemy Movement Around a Maze pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I'm quite new to programming in python and I decided to create a game that is a more basic version of python. I'm having trouble with the A.I, when you run the code the red block(enemy) goes mental and I'm trying to get it to chase the player. As well as that I'm trying to get another enemy to follow random paths around the maze but gave up after i started to develop grey hairs.

```
def move_to_player(self, Player):
    if Player.rect.x > enemy.rect.x:
        enemy.changespeed(1,0)

    elif Player.rect.x < enemy.rect.x:
        enemy.changespeed(-1,0)

    elif Player.rect.y > enemy.rect.y:
        enemy.changespeed(0,1)

    elif Player.rect.y < enemy.rect.y:
        enemy.changespeed(0,-1)
```

Here is the two class's that are being used if it helps. Any help at all would be much appreciated.

```
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):


    #must have constructor line, will always be called
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        # Call the parent's constructor
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        # Set dimensions of player
        self.image = pygame.Surface([25, 25])
        self.image.fill(white) # fill enitre image with "white"

        # The passed in co-ordinates are top left corner where x and y start
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.y = y
        self.rect.x = x

        # Speed of player
        self.x_Change = 0
        self.y_Change = 0

    def changespeed(self, x, y):
        #change speed of player
        self.x_Change += x
        self.y_Change += y   

    def update(self):

        # Move along x axis
        self.rect.x += self.x_Change

        # Did player hit a wall
        block_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, self.walls, False)  # false so it doesn't remove the wall, true would
        for block in block_hit_list:
            # If moving right, place player to the left side of wall

            if self.x_Change > 0:
                self.rect.right = block.rect.left
            else:
                #  if  moving left, do the opposite.
                self.rect.left = block.rect.right

        # Move along y axis
        self.rect.y += self.y_Change

        # Did player hit a wall
        block_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, self.walls, False)
        for block in block_hit_list:

            # Do same as above but on the y axis
            if self.y_Change > 0:
                self.rect.bottom = block.rect.top
            else:
                self.rect.top = block.rect.bottom



class Enemy(pygame.sprite.Sprite):


    #must have constructor line, will always be called
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        # Call the parent's constructor
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        # Set dimensions of enemy
        self.image = pygame.Surface([25, 25])
        self.image.fill(red) # fill enitre image with "white"

        # The passed in co-ordinates are top left corner where x and y start
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.y = y
        self.rect.x = x

        # Speed of player
        self.x_Change = 0
        self.y_Change = 0

    def changespeed(self, x, y):
        #change speed of player
        self.x_Change += x
        self.y_Change += y 


    def move_to_player(self, Player):
        if Player.rect.x > enemy.rect.x:
            enemy.changespeed(1,0)

        elif Player.rect.x < enemy.rect.x:
            enemy.changespeed(-1,0)

        elif Player.rect.y > enemy.rect.y:
            enemy.changespeed(0,1)

        elif Player.rect.y < enemy.rect.y:
            enemy.changespeed(0,-1)




    def update(self):

        # Move along x axis
        self.rect.x += self.x_Change

        # Did player hit a wall
        block_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, self.walls, False)  # false so it doesn't remove the wall, true would
        for block in block_hit_list:
            # If moving right, place player to the left side of wall

            if self.x_Change > 0:
                self.rect.right = block.rect.left
            else:
                #  if  moving left, do the opposite.
                self.rect.left = block.rect.right

        # Move along y axis
        self.rect.y += self.y_Change

        # Did player hit a wall
        block_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, self.walls, False)
        for block in block_hit_list:

            # Do same as above but on the y axis
            if self.y_Change > 0:
                self.rect.bottom = block.rect.top
            else:
                self.rect.top = block.rect.bottom
```

Comment: use button `{}` to correctly format code.

Comment: there is no change to run your code and see problem.

Comment: BTW: in `move_to_player` you should use `self.` instead of `enemy.` - `self.rect.x`, `self.rect.y`, `self.changespeed(...)`.

Comment: so instead of the curly brackets around the co-ordinates, use "{}"?

Comment: and what happens if i use self instead of enemy. Not being rude sorry, just so i know for future reference.

Comment: I can't see full code but `enemy` is external variable which doesn't exist in class `Enemy` - so you change speed not for current Enemy instance but for some different one.

Comment: as for `{}` - when you edit question then there are special buttons to format text - bold, italic, {}, insert image, etc. You have to select code in your text and click `{}` and it will add 4 spaces before **every** line of code - it will inform SO that it is code, not normal text. Normally people manually add 4 spaces before only some lines and SO displays it with wrong indentions.

Comment: Your question is about to get closed because of various reasons. Please take a look at the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and turn your code into a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that we can copy, run and test. You should also try to describe your problems and goals more precisely.

Answer (score 0):

```
def move_to_player(self, Player):
    if Player.rect.x > enemy.rect.x:
        enemy.changespeed(1,0)

    elif Player.rect.x < enemy.rect.x:
        enemy.changespeed(-1,0)

    elif Player.rect.y > enemy.rect.y:
        enemy.changespeed(0,1)

    elif Player.rect.y < enemy.rect.y:
        enemy.changespeed(0,-1)
```

The code above is a logic, not an AI you have coded a set of conditions for it to follow in a particular way.

If you want an AI you would probably want to look at A-star pathfinding. This is what is used in most games nowadays.

Furthermore, about the red block going mental. It maybe because you haven't set the frames per second correctly so the updates the screen is getting is too much changing the movement of the enemy by a lot.